# How to show UIButton over GLKView with UIViewController - IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, glkview

I am new to OpenGL, I have been trying to show a button over the GLKView, but buttons are not showing. Here is what I have done...

```
context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if (!_context) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    }

    glview = [[GLKView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    glview.context = _context;
    glview.delegate = (id)self;
    [self.view addSubview:glview];
```

Edit:

```
 [glview addSubview:call_btn];
```

I have created a UIViewController, added a GLKView as subview to self.view, everything working fine except the above problem (UIbuttons are not shown over the glkview). Any idea how to do it.

Comment: Where and how are you adding those buttons? Adding them as subviews to glView should work just fine. I hope you did set some background color or image to buttons as they are transparent by default and you just don't see them.

Comment: Yeah I set background Image for buttons. Is that matters? What should I do now?

Comment: Add the code where you add the buttons.

Comment: Please check the edit. Call button has background image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906184/ios-creating-an-overlay-on-top-of-an-eaglview-glkview

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add the buttons to the GLKView.
If you add to self.view they are hidden because the GLKView is opaque and in front of them.